# Android - Facebook Open Graph Share Dialog opens, then crashes

Tags: android, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I'm trying to open a Share Dialog inside my app with Open Graph, and it opens properly but after a few seconds crashes.

My code follows the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/#publish-og-with-user-objects but with slightly different constructors for createForPost, though I tried both ways.

```
private void shareToFB(Context context) {
    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentOpenGraphActionDialog(context.getApplicationContext(),
            FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogFeature.OG_ACTION_DIALOG)) {
        OpenGraphObject badge = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost
                (OpenGraphObject.class, "exercisemeapp:badge", "I earned a new badge!",
                        "http://4sqday16.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/foursquare-gym-rat-badge.png",
                        null, "I completed a full body workout for 7 straight days!");
        OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
        action.setProperty("badge", badge);
        action.setType("exercisemeapp:earn");

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(getActivity(), action, "badge")
                .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Facebook not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The only errors I'm seeing in logcat are the following:

```
1525-1525/com.facebook.katana E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.check.CheckOpenSSLImplHasRequiredMethods.<clinit>
1525-1525/com.facebook.katana E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.reflect.SSLParametersGetter.<clinit>
1525-1525/com.facebook.katana E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.reflect.SSLParametersGetter.a
1525-1525/com.facebook.katana E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.reflect.SSLSessionTimeoutSetter.<clinit>
1525-1525/com.facebook.katana E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.ClientSessionContext', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.reflect.SSLSessionTimeoutSetter.a
1525-1525/com.facebook.katana E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.facebook.ssl.openssl.TicketEnabledOpenSSLSocketImplWrapper', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.TicketEnabledOpenSSLSocketFactoryHelper.a
```

And the warning:

```
Exception during service com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: 
(#404) Key hash bMpkGAEDBrEt9w9JMM_UU5Jx-Cc does not match any stored key hashes.
at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:103)
```

Comment: Have you set your application's key correctly? Refer the last section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: Yup, that was the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your app's hash key and the one registered with facebook do not match. This is what facebook [says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/).

> Every Android app you'll create will be signed, and you will need to register each app's key hash with Facebook as a security check for authenticity